# javac: Invalid flag --add modules on ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, javac

I have code working on Windows 7:

`javac -cp .;\"C:/Users/cp/Documents/R DATA/simap/simap.jar\";\"C:/Users/cp/Documents/R DATA/simap/SearchServiceService.jar\" --add-modules java.se.ee \"C:/Users/cp/Documents/R DATA/simap/com.webservice.client/SimapWs.java\"`

While running on Ubuntu `add-modules` flag is missing (also in available options)

the whole error message for the command with --add-modules is:

```
javac: invalid flag: --add-modules
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

How can I overcome this? What flag use instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "flag is missing"?

Comment: There's no option to use it like on Windows
error: `javac: invalid flag: --add-modules`

Comment: Is that the whole error message?